# Compare two files using awk and print the matched lines

Tags: awk

I have two files got following information. i need to compare bothe the files and print lines matched in FILE2.

FILE1.txt

```
martin01
kevin01
phoenix01
samson01
edward01
```

FILE2.txt

```
martin01.test.com empid: 9874712
martin01.test1.com empid:0972292
kevin01.test.com empid: 3297203
kevin01.test.com empid: 3297203
phoenix01.test.com empid: 9872219
phoenix01.test1.com empid:9803994
samson01.test.com empid: 0983903
samson01 empid: 7665758
edward01.test.com empid: 0979072
edward01.test2.com empid: 748840
gregory01.test.com empid: 657758
clevin01.test.com empid:6589598
```

Expected output should be like this:

```
martin01.test.com empid: 9874712
martin01.test1.com empid:0972292
kevin01.test.com empid: 3297203
kevin01.test.com empid: 3297203
phoenix01.test.com empid: 9872219
phoenix01.test1.com empid:9803994
samson01.test.com empid: 0983903
samson01 empid: 7665758
edward01.test.com empid: 0979072
edward01 empid: 748840
```

This is what i wrote but somewhere its wrong..

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' FILE1.txt FILE2.txt
```

Comment: Why edward01 empid? Is it not edward01.test2.com empid?

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the FS to `.`:

```
awk -F'[.[:space:]]' 'FNR==NR {a[$1]; next} $1 in a' FILE1.txt FILE2.txt
```

Comment: Hi Ed , I have modified my question as i want to match the string without the delimiter "." as well

Comment: "edward01 empid: 748840"

Comment: martin01.test.com empid: 9874712
martin01.test1.com empid:0972292
kevin01.test.com empid: 3297203
kevin01.test.com empid: 3297203
phoenix01.test.com empid: 9872219
phoenix01.test1.com empid:9803994
samson01.test.com empid: 0983903
edward01.test.com empid: 0979072

Comment: @user3834663, then use `-F '[.[:space:]]`

Comment: Updated the answer to use `.` or white space as the separator per glenn's suggestion. @A.Danischewski - `-F ""` will, in some awks, split the record into single character fields so idk where you're going with suggesting we use that in this case.

Comment: I looked at it quick and thought you were FS'ing a regex for single character. The char class is the best way, if you know it will be a normal space then you can simply `-F'[. ]'`.

Answer (score 2):

alternative to `awk`

```
$ grep -Ff file1 file2

martin01.test.com empid: 9874712
martin01.test1.com empid:0972292
kevin01.test.com empid: 3297203
kevin01.test.com empid: 3297203
phoenix01.test.com empid: 9872219
phoenix01.test1.com empid:9803994
samson01.test.com empid: 0983903
samson01 empid: 7665758
edward01.test.com empid: 0979072
edward01.test2.com empid: 748840
```

note that the match is anywhere in the line, not confined to first field only.  Use this if your fields are disjoint sets.

Comment: Not bad but it will match file1 anywhere within file2.

Comment: `grep -f <(sed 's/^./^&/g' file1.txt) file2.txt`