# Compare lines from two files and print just a column where it matches

Tags: awk

I am new using AWK. I would thank you if you could help me.

I have two files

file1

```
1   2   3   4   ok  I
5   36  5   6   no  II
58  9   6   4   no  V
4   3   2   1   ok  III
```

file2

```
6   9   8   6
58  6   5   4
4   3   2   1
1   2   3   4
```

I want to find each row from *file2* in file 1 and if it matches print columns 5 and 6 from *file1*

Output expected

```
ok III
ok I
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two files using awk and print the matched lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507407/compare-two-files-using-awk-and-print-the-matched-lines)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: What's your field separator?

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to create a file call match.awk:

```
FNR == NR {
    found[$1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4] = 1
}

FNR != NR && $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4 in found {
    print $5, $6
}
```

Invoke it:

```
awk -f match.awk file2 file1
```

**Discussion**

- Please note that in the command line above, we will go through file2 first. In the script, the processing of file2 is in the first block where `FNR == NR`
- If we encounter lines in file2, we will create a key. For example, if the line contains `58  6   5   4`, then the key will be `58/6/5/4`. With this key, we mark the array `found` with a 1 (true)
- The second block says, "We are seeing a line in file1 and this line has been found in file2. If that is the case, print out the result.

Comment: Don't introduce a random character like `/` as a separator that is then not allowed to appear in the input. Also, reading `file2` first means you can't produce the output in the expected order (the order of the values in `file2`). It doesn't hurt noticeably but the `= 1` in the assignment is doing nothing useful. Lastly, the expression `FNR != NR && $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 "/" $4 in found` could use some parens to improve clarity at least, if not functionality (idk which parts will be evaluated in which order).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 }
NR == FNR {
    map[key] = $5 OFS $6
    next
}
key in map { print map[key] }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
ok III
ok I
```